# Could not determine the installation package com.company.appName

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I can't launch my app anymore on Android. The iOS counterpart seems to be fine.
The full error is:

```
ADB0000: Could not determin the installation path for package.com.company.appname. 
'adb shell pm path com.company.appname' returned.
```

It was working. I pulled some changes from the repo, none of which should have affected any app properties. Actually it was initially launching, but I was getting some odd behavior within the app, so I uninstalled the whole thing off of my phone. Now I cannot launch it at all. What I could find about this error was that my `AndroidManifest.xml` might have a typo, but I couldn't find anything that stuck out. And like I said, there shouldn't have been any changes in there recently. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Steps I have already taken:
1. Clean and rebuild
2. restart VS
3. delete obj and bin folders
4. search for solution on here and xamarin forums

UPDATE: 
I just successfully launched it on another android device. So it seems to be a problem with my Pixel 2 XL. How do I make sure all traces of the app are gone so I can start fresh?

Comment: With your device connected to the computer open the command line and run `adb uninstall package.com.company.appname` If the Android tools are in the Path you will not have any problem otherwise you will need to locate the program *adb* and run the the above command from there

Comment: Thanks. That worked.

Comment: Great tip. In my case it couldn't handle it because it found more than 1 device - physical device (-d) and an emulator (-e). No need to unplug either. Use `adb -d uninstall com.company.appname` and `adb -e uninstall com.company.appname` respectively.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This usually happens when you have more than one user in an Android device (I still cannot figure out why is this).

As mentioned in the comment by using the `adb uninstall full.package.name` command it will uninstall the app.

But there's another way which does not require command line or nothing related to that.

If you go to the Settings -> Apps and Notifications on the Android device you will be able to uninstall it from there.

Let's use the **UnoQuickStart.Droid** app as example here. As you can see it's already in the same state as it was yours.

[image]

Once in the App details both Uninstall and Force Stop are disabled. But do you see those 3 dots image at the right upper corner? Click on it.

[image]

This will bring you a context menu with a single option "Uninstall for all users". You can click on it with confidence.

[image]

As expected, a warning message telling you what's gonna happen. Just click "Ok".

[image]

As you can see the App is not longer installed and you will now be able to install it again.

[image]

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Great answer, thanks! this happened on a Kindle Fire HD 10, fixed.

Comment: perfect, I overlooked the option "Uninstall for all users". This was the fix for me.

Answer (score 8):

As per apineda's instructions, using `adb unistall com.company.appname` fixed the problem. I was able to get to the ADB location by navigating through Visual Studio -> Tools -> Android -> Android ADB Command Prompt.

Before I did that, I looked at the App list for my phone, which listed the app, but apparently not installed for this user. The `Uninstall` and `Force Stop` buttons were disabled and several of the fields just said `loading...` or something like that.