# Deployment issue, works on my friends phone but not my phone

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This error message gets thrown when im trying to deploy my project in xamarins on to my android phone. It works on my friends phone but not on my.[image]

```
Error       ADB1000:  Deployment failed
Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: InternalError ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not determine the installation path for package com.companyname.app9. `adb shell pm path com.companyname.app9` returned ''.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.<GetPackageRemotePathAsync>d__39.MoveNext() in C:\A\_work\115\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Devices\AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:line 672
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.<GetFastDevRemotePathAsync>d__44.MoveNext() in C:\A\_work\115\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Devices\AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:line 737
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<GetFastDevRemotePathAsync>d__115.MoveNext() in C:\A\_work\115\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Sessions\AndroidDeploySession.cs:line 504
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<FastDevAsync>d__114.MoveNext() in C:\A\_work\115\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Sessions\AndroidDeploySession.cs:line 471
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunAsync>d__106.MoveNext() in C:\A\_work\115\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Sessions\AndroidDeploySession.cs:line 225
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunLoggedAsync>d__104.MoveNext() in C:\A\_work\115\s\External\androidtools\Xamarin.AndroidTools\Sessions\AndroidDeploySession.cs:line 119          0
```

Comment: On your phone go into settings and find all the apps that are installed. Even though the app might not show up as an icon on your phone anymore, it can still be installed. Make sure that in the app management screen you uninstalled the app completely then try again

Comment: @GeraldVersluis could not find it in apps

Comment: @ChristianKhalil Hi, what's the device of your friend? If using Android 10 physical device , we need to continue to click accept dialog window when installing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Make sure that fast deployments are disabled on the debug configuration
2. Turn on Shared Runtime if you are running on Android 6 or above to speed up future deployments
3. Rename the android package name to something like com.sample_company.sample_app (Just for now, you can change the name later)
4. Clean and Rebuild the solution

If that does not work, then please try this solution here and scroll to pinedax answer:

[Could not determine the installation package com.company.appName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54245275/could-not-determine-the-installation-package-com-company-appname)