# How to uninstall an android app properly with it's signature?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, uninstallation, android-keystore, mobile-development

I have manually uninstalled my on going development app on my Android phone via Visual Studio, but later when I'm trying to reinstall the app, I'm getting this error "Conflicting app signature."

But the app is already uninstalled and I couldn't find any file by searching it's name on my file explorer, I also tried to follow this one [Could not determine the installation package com.company.appName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54245275/could-not-determine-the-installation-package-com-company-appname), It worked with my emulator [face this problem in my emulator too] but not working with my physical phone (**Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 Pro**). I can't see any trace of my app.

My app is made with Xamarin.Forms

[image: Conflicting app signature.]

Comment: I checked and there is only one google account is connected to my phone. :(

Comment: Read [this article](https://technosamigos.com/how-to-resolve-conflicting-signature-error-android-apk/) may help. It probably caused by the previous is not completely uninstalled.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes manually remove the app in the phone will have that issue. To fix use the `adb` command line in your terminal to uninstall the app, this will completely remove it.

`adb uninstall yourAppPackageNameHere`

You'll need to have adb installed if you don't have it already.